# Replace the values of first 100 rows of a subsetted dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
gender <- sample( c("M","F"), 10000, replace=TRUE, prob=c( 0.5, 0.5) )
handed <- sample( c("L","R"), 10000, replace=TRUE, prob=c( 0.2, 0.8) )
data <- data.frame(gender=gender,handed=handed)
```

I need to replace the first 100 rows which comes from this subset

```
d <- subset(data,gender=="M" & handed=="R",)
```

I know the

```
da <- head(d,n=100)
```

but I don't know how to replace them in `data`.

I want to replace it with:

```
gender=="F" & handed=="L
```

I have tried this solution:

```
Conditions_Seperator<-function(condition){return (unlist(strsplit(condition, "")))}
  con<-Conditions_Seperator("MR")
  replaceing_con<-Conditions_Seperator("FL")

      library(data.table)
      setDT(data)[data[,  .I[gender==as.character(con[1]) &  handed == as.character(con[2])][1:size_to_decrease]],
                  c('gender', 'handed') := .(as.character(replaceing_con[1]), as.character(replaceing_con[2]))][]
```

and the output is:

```
      handed
gender    L    R    M
     F 6122   95 3592
     M   96   95    0
```

**it adds one column to my dataset**

Comment: What do you want to replace it with?

Comment: oh sorry `gender=="F" & handed=="L`

Comment: You can include that update by editing your post. Also include `set.seed` for a reproducible example. You should probably also make this data smaller, maybe 100 obs and replace the first 10 or something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411231/r-replace-rows-in-a-data-frame-based-on-criteria

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R Replace rows in a data frame based on criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411231/r-replace-rows-in-a-data-frame-based-on-criteria)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a second base R method that uses double subscripting.

Using ronak-shah's data, we start with

```
with(data, table(gender, handed))
      handed
gender L R
     F 0 4
     M 1 5
```

of each group, then use

```
data[data$gender=="M" & data$handed=="R",][1:2,] <- data.frame(gender="F", handed="L")
```

to replace the first two right-handed males with left-handed females. We end up with

```
with(data, table(gender, handed))
      handed
gender L R
     F 2 4
     M 1 3
```

Answer (score 2):

We can try by finding the position of first 100 "TRUE" values with `which` and `head` and use those indexes to subset rows in the original dataframe and update them by generating vector of values to be updated using `rep`.

```
subs <- head(which(data$gender=="M" & data$handed=="R"), 100)
data[subs, ] <- rep(c("F", "L"), each = 100)
```

Just for reproducibility, a small example with 10 rows and updating only 2 rows.

```
set.seed(24)
gender <- sample( c("M","F"), 10, replace=TRUE, prob=c( 0.5, 0.5) )
handed <- sample( c("L","R"), 10, replace=TRUE, prob=c( 0.2, 0.8) )
data <- data.frame(gender=gender,handed=handed)
data
#   gender handed
#1       F      R
#2       F      R
#3       M      R
#4       M      R
#5       M      R
#6       M      L
#7       F      R
#8       M      R
#9       M      R
#10      F      R

subs <- head(which(data$gender=="M" & data$handed=="R"), 2)
subs
#[1] 3 4
data[subs, ] <- rep(c("F", "L"), each = 2)
data
#   gender handed
#1       F      R
#2       F      R
#3       F      L
#4       F      L
#5       M      R
#6       M      L
#7       F      R
#8       M      R
#9       M      R
#10      F      R
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[data[,  .I[gender=="M" &  handed == "R"][1:100]],
                        c('gender', 'handed') := .('F', 'L')][]
#       gender handed
#    1:      F      R
#    2:      F      R
#    3:      M      L
#    4:      F      L
#    5:      M      L
#   ---              
# 9996:      F      R
# 9997:      F      R
# 9998:      F      R
# 9999:      M      L
#10000:      M      R
```

---

For the updated question

```
setDT(data)[data[, .I[gender==con[1] & handed == con[2]][seq_len(size_to_decrease)]],
      c('gender', 'handed') := .(replaceing_con[1], replaceing_con[2])][]

table(data)
#      handed
#gender    L    R
#     F 1068 4075
#     M  986 3871
```

Comment: @user5363938  I am not getting any new column

Comment: I know ur solution works well, but i have updated my question, can u help me with this one? @akrun

Comment: `head(data[filter, which=TRUE], 100)` might be another way of selecting those rows.

Comment: @user5363938 It's the same as this, like `setDT(data)[some_rows, (some_cols) := some_values]`. Actually, I did not read the question, only the answers so far. Fyi, the etiquette here is that you shouldn't substantially modify your question after answers have been posted unless all answerers told you to go ahead with it. Otherwise, best to post a new question (after attempting the new problem yourself, of course).